# Import and Export CSV using PowerShell with all columns in double quotes

Tags: powershell, csv

I am using below code to import and export to CSV. The reason why I am doing an export is because I need all columns in the exported CSV to be enclosed in double quotes. But with below code the double quote is only appearing at the first and last of every line.

```
Import-Csv c:\Emp.csv | Export-Csv c:\Emp1.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Please note that I have already tried below code (that works but takes longer time if size of CSV is > 200MB):

```
$inform = Get-Content C:\A.csv 
$inform | % { 
  $info = $_.ToString().Replace("|", """|""") 
  $info += """" 
  $var = """" + $info 
  $var | Out-File D:\B.csv -Append 
}
```

Sample input (CSV file):

```
1|A|Test|ABC,PQR
```

Sample output (CSV file):

```
"1"|"A"|"Test"|"ABC,PQR"
```

Comment: Please post sample input, and output for each piece of code. What is the reason for this requirement? AFAIK PowerShell follows [the IETF standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) so will enclose in quotes only if required (i.e. the values have special characters).

Comment: Its infact putting the entire line into double quotes as below

` "1|A|Test|ABC,PQR" `

Comment: `Export-Csv` already does what you want, but you're using a custom delimiter (`|`), so you need to specify that as `-Delimiter '|'` for both `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv`.

Comment: That works! Good catch! Thanks.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers
The Export-Csv does solves my problem but I have huge CSV files which become more huge after all columns in CSV files are enclosed in double quotes. Can we tweak it to enclose double quotes only for those columns having comma's



Input:
`1|2|ABC,PQR `

Output
`1|2|"ABC,PQR"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Export-Csv` already adds double quotes around each field by itself, so all you need to do for that is instruct it to use the correct delimiter:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' -Delimiter '|' |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoType
```

However, `Export-Csv` adds quotes around all fields indiscriminately, so if you want to selectively add quotes around particular fields you're going to need a custom routine:

```
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader 'C:\path\to\input.csv'
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter 'C:\path\to\output.csv'

while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
    $line = $reader.ReadLine().Split('|')
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $line.Count; $i++) {
        if ($line[$i] -like '*,*') {
            $line[$i] = '"{0}"' -f $line[$i]
        }
    }
    $writer.WriteLine(($line -join '|'))
}

$reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
$writer.Close(); $writer.Dispose()
```