# PowerShell script to replace comma's in CSV file with nothing

Tags: powershell

Below is my script to replace comma's in an existing CSV file. The delimiter used is |  The script works perfectly fine but takes a long time to replace. Do we have a faster approach to replace all instances of comma's with nothing.

```
$inform = Get-Content C:\product.csv
                $inform | % { 
                $info = $_.ToString().Replace(",","")                
                $info  | Out-file C:\product_comma_replaced.csv -Append 
                }
```

Input CSV:

```
1|Test,ABC|Test,LMN
```

Output CSV:

```
1|TestABC|TestLMN
```

Comment: So, do you want to remove commas, or do you want to [put fields with commas in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45011963/1630171)? Which is it?

Comment: put fields with commas in double quotes - This is a separate requirement, don't have the answer yet

I got the answer for this post(replace comma's with nothing), it was indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$inform = Get-Content C:\product.csv
$inform.ToString()
$y=$inform -replace ',' -replace ''
 $y  | Out-file C:\product_comma_replaced.csv -Append
```

Comment: This is not recommended an approach if working with large (100s of megabytes to gigabytes or larger) files.

Comment: I agree Sir,But Looking at the problem defination i presumed it to be lesser than a mb/Max 10 mb and its the easiest and quickest fix i feel.Just giving out a simple fix to the simple problem. :)

Comment: 1048576 rows csv translates to 600 mb,I Hope @joseph Doesnt have that huge data